# Spotify ads are very too loud comparing to the music volume

Tags: audio, spotify

I recently installed Spotify on my PC. I'm listening music approximately at half of the volume bar.

[image: volume bar]

When an ad starts, this is terribly too loud comparing to the music volume. Probably twice louder. It hurts my ears.

**Is there a way adjust the ad volume ?** Or to fix this problem ?

Comment: [EZBlocker – Spotify Ad Blocker](https://www.ericzhang.me/projects/spotify-ad-blocker-ezblocker/) - EZBlocker is a simple-to-use ad blocker for Spotify. The latest version of EZBlocker will attempt to block ads on Spotify from loading. If an ad does load, EZBlocker will mute Spotify until the ad is over

Comment: @DavidPostill you need to make this an answer, I was looking for exactly this the other day and couldn't find it. This is a helpful post and should be able to be voted up as such.

Comment: @MattKing Answer provided ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer [on the official website](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web/Video-ads-way-too-loud/td-p/1043678) that requires no 3rd party software installation. You just have to change volume settings like described :

> There is a workaround described above that stands:
>
> Set the volume on the Spotify player software to maximum. Then adjust
>   the computer output volume back to a comfortable level. No more loud ads.
>
> Problem lies in the fact that Spotify allows advertisers to adjust the
>   player volume, against your will, when their ad is played, overriding
>   the player volume setting you have set yourself. Naturally they set it
>   to max - because they can!
>
> When you set the volume of the player to max yourself, the ads cannot
>   increase volume anymore higher than you now listen to your music at.
>   Effectively you have created a ceiling to the audio volume.
>
> This results music and ads be played at the uniform level. And you still
>   can set the actual output volume to any level you like via the computer
>   volume setting.
>
> Tested. I can confirm this is an effective workaround, that Spotify
>   cannot bypass without your consent.

Comment: I always have my Spotify on full volume and the ads still play way louder than the music.

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there a way adjust the spotify ad volume? Or to fix this problem?

Two options.

1. Install [EZBlocker](https://www.ericzhang.me/projects/spotify-ad-blocker-ezblocker/):

   > EZBlocker is a simple-to-use ad blocker for Spotify. The latest
   >   version of EZBlocker will attempt to block ads on Spotify from
   >   loading. If an ad does load, EZBlocker will mute Spotify until the ad
   >   is over.
   >
   > There are no fancy features, just pure ad blocking. When an ad is
   >   blocked, only Spotify is muted, so no other sounds will be affected.
   >   EZBlocker aims to be the most stable and reliable ad blocker for
   >   Spotify.
   >
   > There’s no setup required – just drag it into any folder and run. To
   >   upgrade your EZBlocker, simply replace the executable.
   >
   > [image]
   >
   > EZBlocker requires .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows 7/8/10.
2. Upgrade to the [premium version](https://www.spotify.com/uk/premium/):

   > £9.99 /month
   >
   > - Shuffle play
   > - Ad free
   > - Unlimited skips
   > - Listen offline
   > - Play any track
   > - High quality audio

Spotify Premium is 50% off for students at the time this answer was posted.

Comment: If you have a student email address Spotify Premium is only $5/month. (US only I think?)

Comment: @jatuttle0 I can't access the US prices, but I added the UK student discount to the answer (50%).